# Unable to add Apple ID in VS2017 and VS2019 Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, provisioning-profile, apple-id

I'm having a hard time trying to deploy my first Xamarin.Forms app to an iPhone. This is the scenario:

-coding on Visual Studio for Windows (VS2017 Community 15.9.24 and VS2019 Community 16.8.5);

-VS running on Windows 7

-MacBookPro on the same network, logged in with my personal Apple ID;

-iPhone attached to the Mac;

-I created an Apple developer account (not a paid account)

-Xcode and VS installed on the Mac;

-pairing to the Mac works fine;

-debugging the Xamarin iOS project using iPhone simulator works fine;

-debugging on a physical iPhone attached to the Mac fails in both VS2017 and VS2019.

I understand the error must be because I can't add my Apple ID in Visual Studio.

**Error in VS2017:**

-I select iOS Options > iOS Bundle signing > Automatic provisioning;

-then in Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple accounts VS won't let me add an account. The only enabled option is the "install Fastlane" button, which fails.

-trying to run the debug configuration on the iPhone anyway fails with the error "No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com." Can't get past this point.
[vs2017 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQGng.png)

**Error in VS2019:**

-iOS Options > iOS Bundle signing shows the message "Please wait until the provisioning information is loaded" forever. No options are presented.

-in Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple accounts > Add I type my Apple developer ID and password, but nothing happens. I can barely see what I suppose is a message box flicking on and off.

-trying to run the debug configuration on the iPhone anyway fails with error "Automatic provisioning is  enabled but no development team was selected." Can't go further here also.
[vs2019 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk3Mh.png)

Am I missing something here? Is there a workaround? Online documentation that I've found won't help me with these errors.

EDIT: I was able to add my Apple Id into VS2019 running on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you receive confirmation from Apple that developer account is active? You need to create provision profile, certificate, then install it. Application id must be the same in all this places. Devices UUID as well. Try to go through steps described here again very carefully https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=windows

Comment: @DenisK. Actually I didn't. I was struggling to get my ID onto VS first. Today I found I could do it in VS2019 on W10. Thanks.

Comment: @mdossa If you have solved that, remember to update it as an answer when you have time. It will be helpful for others who have the same problem.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I don't think I found the answer to my original questions, but a way around the problem. I still don't know what was happening. Would it be acceptable as an answer?